# iterar sobre clases

Tags: python-3.x

quiero sumar +1 a una variable por objeto que le pase a una función. De normal, solo se le pasa un objeto, una clase, y no puedo iterar sobre ella con un range(), ¿qué forma habría de hacerlo?

Os pongo la fracción del código que me genera la duda y por si lo necesitarais, el código completo:

```py
    def eliminar_dados(self, eliminar_enemigo=None, list(eliminar_aliado=None)):
        """ Elimina aliados o enemigos específicos del grupo adecuado. """
        def metodo_eliminar(eliminados, grupo):
            """ Submétodo para eliminar los dados especificados. """
            for i in eliminados:
                grupo.remove(i)
        if eliminar_enemigo is not None:
            metodo_eliminar(eliminar_enemigo, self.grupo_enemigo)
        if eliminar_aliado is not None:
            for i in range(len(eliminar_aliado)):
                self.cementerio += 1
            metodo_eliminar(eliminar_aliado, self.grupo_aliado)
```

```py
from random import choices
""" Importa choices para generar opciones aleatorios con una probabilidad específica. """

class Dados:
    """ Crea un objeto, enemigo o compañero, con los atributos figura y color. """
    caras_grupo = {
        "Guerrero":"Verde",
        "Templario":"Blanco",
        "Mago":"Azul",
        "Ladrón":"Morado",
        "Pergamino":"Marrón",
        "Campeón":"Amarillo"
    }

    caras_mazmorra = {
        "Goblin":"Verde",
        "Esqueleto":"Blanco",
        "Ghoul":"Azul",
        "Cofre":"Morado",
        "Pocima":"Naranja",
        "Dragón":"Rojo"
    }

    def __init__(self, tipo, figura=None):
        """ Devuelve el par clave:valor de un diccionario. Donde la clave es una figura y el valor un color. """
        if tipo == "enemigo":
            self.caras = dict(Dados.caras_mazmorra)

        if tipo == "aliado":
            self.caras = dict(Dados.caras_grupo)

        if figura is None:
            posibilidades = [i for i in self.caras.keys()]
            eleccion = choices(posibilidades, weights=[2,2,2,2,1,1])
            self.figura, self.color = eleccion[0], self.caras[eleccion[0]]
        else:
            self.figura, self.color = figura, self.caras[figura]


class Acciones:
    """ Acciones de los dados en dungeon roll. """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Inicializa los grupos enemigos y aliados como listas. """
        self.grupo_aliado = []
        self.grupo_enemigo = []
        self.dragones = []
        self.cementerio = 0

    def add(self, tipo, figura=None, cantidad=1):
        """ 
        Añade aliados o enemigos a sus respectivos grupos.
        Tipo: si es aliado o enemigo.
        Figura: si queremos que sea aleatoria o nosotros especificamos una. Bastaría con poner el nombre de la figura.
        Cantidad: por defecto, para añadir siempre se debe añadir 1. Puede añadirse tantos como se quieran.
        Devuelve True o False según si en el grupo enemigo hay dragones.
        """
        if tipo == "enemigo":
            dado = self.grupo_enemigo
        if tipo == "aliado":
            dado = self.grupo_aliado
        for i in range(cantidad):
            dado.append(Dados(tipo, figura)) # Llama al método notas y le agrega el resultado a la respectiva lista, enemigo o aliado.
        for i in self.grupo_enemigo:
            if i.figura == "Dragón":
                self.dragon = True
                return
        self.dragon = False    

    def eliminar_dados(self, eliminar_enemigo=None, list(eliminar_aliado=None)):
        """ Elimina aliados o enemigos específicos del grupo adecuado. """
        def metodo_eliminar(eliminados, grupo):
            """ Submétodo para eliminar los dados especificados. """
            for i in eliminados:
                grupo.remove(i)
        if eliminar_enemigo is not None:
            metodo_eliminar(eliminar_enemigo, self.grupo_enemigo)
        if eliminar_aliado is not None:
            for i in range(len(eliminar_aliado)):
                self.cementerio += 1
            metodo_eliminar(eliminar_aliado, self.grupo_aliado)

    def guarida_dragon(self):
        """ Elimina los dragones del grupo enemigo y los añade a la guarida """
        for i in self.grupo_enemigo:
            if i.figura == "Dragón":
                self.dragones.append(i)
        for i in self.dragones:
            if i in self.grupo_enemigo:
                self.grupo_enemigo.remove(i)

    def mostrar_dados(self):
        for i in range(len(self.grupo_enemigo)):
            print(i+1, self.grupo_enemigo[i].figura, self.grupo_enemigo[i].color)

        print("")

        for i in range(len(self.grupo_aliado)):
            print(i+1, self.grupo_aliado[i].figura, self.grupo_aliado[i].color)

    def seleccionar(self):
        self.mostrar_dados()

        while True:
            self.a_juego = int(input("Escoge un alidado para la batalla: "))
            if self.a_juego == "" or self.a_juego <= 0 or self.a_juego > len(self.grupo_aliado):
                print("Introduce una posición válida para el aliado")
            else:
                self.a_juego = self.grupo_aliado[self.a_juego-1]
                break

        self.b_juego = []
        while True:
            b_j = int(input("Introduce un enemigo. 0 para dejar de seleccionar: "))

            if b_j == "" or b_j < 0 or b_j > len(self.grupo_enemigo):
                print("Introduce una posición válida para el grupo enemigo.")
            elif b_j == 0: 
                if self.b_juego:
                    break
                else:
                    print("Selecciona al menos un enemigo.")
            elif b_j in self.b_juego:
                print("Ya has escodigo ese enemigo")
            else:
                self.b_juego.append(self.grupo_enemigo[b_j])
```

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis `list(eliminar_aliado=None)` es inválida simplemente porque con ella tratas de pasar a la función `list` mediante un argumento tipo keyword `eliminar_aliado` el valor `None`. `list` logicamente no tiene ningún argumento `eliminar_aliado`. Es más, si hicieras `list(eliminar_aliado)` seguiría siendo inválido por dos razones:

- Si `eliminar_aliado` es una instancia de `Dados`, `list()` intentará iterar sobre el para construir la lista y `Dados` no es iterable.
- Lo anterior ni siquiera llegaría a ocurrir porque se produciría un `NameError` al ejecutar el código al no estar `eliminar_aliado` definido. **Los argumentos por defecto son evaluados** cuando el intérprete genera el objeto representativo de la función y lo carga en memoria al ejecutar el módulo, **en tiempo de definición**, no cuando se llama a la función (tiempo de ejecución):

  ```
  bar = 5

  def foo(a=bar):
      print(a)
  ```

  > >>> foo()
  >   5
  >   >>> bar = 8
  >   >>> foo()
  >   5

Podrías simplemente llamar a la función englobando la instancia en una lista:

```
dados = Dados()
self.eliminar_dados(eliminar_aliado=[dados])
```

pero si quieres que los argumentos acepten `None`, una sola instancia de `Dados` o una lista, debes comprobar el tipo del objeto asociado al argumento dentro de la propia función. Para ello puedes usar `isinstance` y actuar en consecuentemente según el tipo de objeto recibido:

```
def eliminar_dados(self, eliminar_enemigo=None, eliminar_aliado=None):
    """ Elimina aliados o enemigos específicos del grupo adecuado. """
    def metodo_eliminar(eliminados, grupo):
        """ Submétodo para eliminar los dados especificados. """
        for i in eliminados:
            grupo.remove(i)

    if eliminar_enemigo is not None:
        if isinstance(eliminar_enemigo, Dados):
            eliminar_enemigo = [eliminar_enemigo]
        elif isinstance(eliminar_enemigo, list):
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError("eliminar_enemigo debe ser list, Dados o None")
        metodo_eliminar(eliminar_enemigo, self.grupo_enemigo)

    if eliminar_aliado is not None:
        if isinstance(eliminar_enemigo, Dados):
            eliminar_aliado = [eliminar_aliado]
        elif isinstance(eliminar_aliado, list):
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError("eliminar_aliado debe ser list, Dados o None")
        metodo_eliminar(eliminar_aliado, self.grupo_aliado)
        self.cementerio += len(eliminar_aliado)
```

Para incrementar el valor de `self.cementerio` usa `len` en vez de iterar con un `for`, es más simple y eficiente.